# EntityType 'CustomUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType

Tags: entity-framework, webforms, asp.net-identity

I've just started a new project in Web Forms because I thought it'd be quicker than learning MVC, but how wrong was I!  I'm struggling with the Identity aspect of my project.  I've followed this link here: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity

And it all compiles ok and works (my ID column is now an integer).

So I've created a new class for a 'Property' context:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace MyApp.Models
{
public class PropertyContext : DbContext
{
    public PropertyContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Property> Property { get; set; }      

}

public class Property
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int PropertyID { get; set; }

    //[Required, StringLength(128)]
    //public string OwnerID { get; set; }

  //  [ForeignKey("OwnerID")]
    //public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    //[ForeignKey("OwnerID")]
    //public int OwnerID { get; set; }
   // public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }


    public int OwnerID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("OwnerID")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser ID { get; set; }


    [Required, StringLength(255), Display(Name = "Address 1")]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(255), Display(Name = "Address 2")]
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(255), Display(Name = "Address 3")]
    public string Address3 { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(255), Display(Name = "Town/City")]
    public string Settlement { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(255), Display(Name = "County")]
    public string County { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(255), Display(Name = "Post Code")]
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(255), Display(Name = "Country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

}

}
```

Whereby I'm trying to make a new int column called 'OwnerID' a foreign key into the 'AspNetUser' table's ID column.  When i build my project, it builds fine.  However when I try to add a migration I get this:

```
MyApp.Models.CustomUserLogin: : EntityType 'CustomUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
MyApp.Models.CustomUserRole: : EntityType 'CustomUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
CustomUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'CustomUserLogins' is based on type 'CustomUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
CustomUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'CustomUserRoles' is based on type 'CustomUserRole' that has no keys defined.
```

So in my ApplicationDbContext I've added this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users").HasKey<int>(u => u.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles").HasKey(ur => new { ur.RoleId, ur.UserId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins").HasKey<int>(ul => ul.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims").HasKey<int>(uc => uc.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomRole>().ToTable("Roles").HasKey<int>(r => r.Id);



    }
```

and even this

```
base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserLogin>().HasKey(cul => cul.UserId);
modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserRole>().HasKey(cur => cur.UserId);
```

But it still doesn't work.  And to be quite honest I'm burning up a whole weekend by stabbing in the dark.  I can't believe something as simple as creating a foreign key is so difficult in this Entity Framework environment.

Can anybody give me a pointer?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I did exactly as you did.

- Added Identity to my MVC Web Application
- Changed the primary key to be an INT rather a GUID
- Added an EmployeeProfile and a CustomerProfile to the ApplicationUser

I did not have to override OnModelCreating as I made my own changes to the database tables to support what I needed.

[image]

[image]

Added two new properties to the ApplicationUser class in IdentityModels.cs

```
 public virtual CustomerProfile CustomerProfile { get; set; }

 public virtual EmployeeProfile EmployeeProfile { get; set; }
```

I created the CustomerProfile and EmployeeProfile classes. Note the Data Annotations on the Id property of each class.  The Id property is the ForeignKey property to guide the virtual User property back to the ApplicationUser.

```
 public class EmployeeProfile
{       
    [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate{ get; set; }        

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

}

public class CustomerProfile
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public CustomerType CustomerType { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string WorkPhone { get; set; }       
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }     
    public string AccountType { get; set; } 

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

In my ApplicationDbContext class, I added the following lines of code:

```
public DbSet<CustomerProfile> CustomerProfile { get; set; }
public DbSet<EmployeeProfile> EmployeeProfile { get; set; }
```

Everything was working as expected.  I logged in and saw the Customer and Employee info in my views.

I started seeing the error you received "**EntityType 'CustomUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType**" when I added a many to many relation ship in the EmployeeProfile class to a Departments class.  In my scenario an Employee can belong to 1 or many departments and a department can have many employees.  My database changes were good and even the classes compiled just like you experienced, however once I ran the project, the website would error out.

Backing out my changes resolved the issue.  Something in my classes was throwing off the validation of the model, so I'll need to approach the problem differently.  So just like in my case, your poco classes may have an issue.

Remove your 'Property' class and references.  Make the project work with the base essentials.  Once you have it working, add the Property class back in with just the Id property.

Let me know if you still need help.

Answer (score 0):

Place the `base.OnModelCreating` at the bottom:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users").HasKey<int>(u => u.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles").HasKey(ur => new { ur.RoleId, ur.UserId });
    modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins").HasKey<int>(ul => ul.UserId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims").HasKey<int>(uc => uc.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<CustomRole>().ToTable("Roles").HasKey<int>(r => r.Id);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```